# Back Space Causes Crash in Calculator

Tags: android-studio, debugging, kotlin, crash, calculator

When ever I press the Back Space button when there is no input, the Android Calculator app Crashes.
This code is written in Kotlin and the IDE is Android Studio and the BackSpace is labeled tvBack in MainActivity.kt in the Code below.

What should i do to Handle this crash?

```
 //BACK
        tvBack.setOnClickListener{
            val string =tvResult.text.toString()
            val string2=tvExpression.text.toString()
            if(string.isEmpty()){
                tvExpression.text = string2.substring(0,string2.length-1)

            }else if(string2.isNotEmpty()){

                tvResult.text=""
            }else if(string2.isEmpty()){
                return@setOnClickListener
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is this line:

```
tvExpression.text = string2.substring(0,string2.length-1)
```

If your string2 is empty, `string2.length` is 0, so this line evaluates as

```
tvExpression.text = string2.substring(0,-1)
```

So it's an invalid substring.

So before generating a substring you should first check if the string is not empty. You can do this by adding the following line after `tvBack.setOnClickListener{`:

```
if (string2.length == 0) return;
```

// EDIT:
Please edit your code to the following:

```
    tvBack.setOnClickListener{
        val string =tvResult.text.toString()
        val string2=tvExpression.text.toString()
        if(string2.isNotEmpty()){
            tvExpression.text = string2.substring(0,string2.length-1)
            tvResult.text=""
        }
```

The problem for your new error was, that you did your checks wrong.
You only want to generate and use a substring if the string is **not** empty. Your code did the opposite

Comment: thus saying Thanks is prohibited , i should say i appreciate your answer

Comment: Addition: I just realized kotlin has a built on function for checking the emptiness of a string so using `string2.isEmpty()` is good practice here.

Comment: It still doesnt work , the app keeps crashing after i press 'tvBack' multiply times , when 'tvResult' and 'tvExpression' have " " value .

Comment: i edited the code up there, like you mentioned i still get the problem

Comment: Edited my solution, please check